# How can I fix the regex spacing

Tags: regex, pcre

My regex expression: `(?:LD |(?:[a-zILT]+ ?))` 
My test string: `Green 4 Green 4 Green 7 WI LD Green 9 Green 9 Red 3 Red 3 Red 4 WI LD Draw Four Red 5 Red Reverse Yellow 0 Yellow Skip Green 8 WI LD Draw Four`

https://regex101.com/r/aD0oS2/5

If you look below at SUBSTITUTION in regex101 it returns:

`G4 G4 G7 WG9 G9 R3 R3 R4 WDFR5 RRY0 YSG8 WDF`

How can I fix the spacing for this? I want it to return something like:

`G4 G4 G7 W G9 G9 R3 R3 R4 WDF R5 RR Y0 YS G8 WDF`

Comment: What are the specifications? What spaces are to be kept/where should they be added?

Comment: spaces after the numbers/Reverse/Skip/Draw Two/Draw Four need to be kept. All other spaces should be removed. So: `Green 4`  should become `G4`, `Green Reverse Yellow 6` should become `GR Y6`.

Comment: Was the extra space in `WI LD` intended?

Comment: @McGlothlin Yes, it's intended.

Comment: With [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/dV2nZ1/2) (Version 2) I almost get what you need. No idea how to get a space after `W` in `G4 G4 G7 W G9`. What is the requirement here?

Comment: There `WI LD` which should turn into `W` and `WI LD Draw Four` which should turn into `WDF`. So for e.g. `WI LD Green 6` should be `W G6` and  `WI LD Draw Four Green 6` should be `WDF G6`

Comment: Ok, looks like [Version 4](https://regex101.com/r/dV2nZ1/4) should work for you.

Comment: @stribizhev That worked thanks alot :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also, tried playing with it again and I ended up with: `(?:(?:[a-z]|I LD)| (?!Red|Green|Blue|Yellow|WI LD))` and it seems to work fine.

https://regex101.com/r/aD0oS2/6

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8096fbcda5cc5c3878531f069dc0d3af5289852

Comment: If it's working you could just edit the post or remove it.

Comment: @stribizhev It says that I can not remove it, since this post has already answers. I've no idea what I should edit in this post I'm relatively new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, I upvoted your posts, when it is possible, you can accept your solution.

Comment: @stribizhev, thanks! It says that I have to wait 2 days before I can accept the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

If using PCRE, the `(?|...)` notation allows multiple captures to all share the same capture number, as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/rV4yH6/1).

```
(W)I LD(?: (D)raw (F)our)?|(D)raw (?|(T)wo|(F)our)|(?:(?|(R)ed|(G)reen|(Y)ellow|(B)lue) (?|(S)kip|(R)everse|(\d)))
```

replaced with

```
\1\2\3\4\5\6\7
```

should give you the output

```
G4 G4 G7 W G9 G9 R3 R3 R4 WDF R5 RR Y0 YS G8 WDF
```

You can see multiple input cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/rV4yH6/2).